# What is the name of the anti-pattern that avoids using callbacks by using delayed function calls?

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, design-patterns, anti-patterns

I've seen this anti-pattern in many places while maintaining some code for an Android application, and I don't know what to call it. Basically, `function1` is an asynchronous function that needs to be followed by `function2`. Instead of putting `function2` in a callback that will execute when `function1` is completed, the programmer decided to first schedule a delayed call to `function2` with an arbitrary time and then call `function1`.

```
void foo() {
    // delayed call to function2
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            function2();
        }
    }, 1000);

    // call function1
    function1();
}
```

I can only assume this was done because it's simpler and quicker than defining an interface that accepts callbacks. I just want to know if it has a name and maybe some specific documentation on how to properly handle this situation.

Comment: I'll call it "The minecraft antipattern" because I presume that's where this pattern is the most learned; due to the design of pretty much any async system in that whole community. It also became much more prevalant around that time from what I've seen.

Comment: Since the delay is more or less a thread sleep, you might call it the [sleep anti-pattern](https://faculty.uoit.ca/bradbury/concurr-catalog/sleep.html).

Comment: @jaco0646 The context is completely different, but after reading that page, I can definitely see the parallels. Although a sleep and this type of scheduling-delay are very different, in this context they are basically equivalent, and the logic after a join can be compared to a callback. It's probably as close as I'm going to get. Thanks.